# How can I select the Kendo UI dropdownlist value?

Tags: kendo-ui

How can I select the Kendo drop down list value on change function. The Kendo dropdownlist is in grid. On change function I want to select the first item in the list.

I have written the code:

```
       function categoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {

        var dropdownlist = $('<input data-text-field="category" id ="ctdd" data-value-field="CatId" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>').appendTo(container).kendoDropDownList({
            optionLabel: "Select...",
            dataValueField: "categoryid",
            dataTextField: "category",
            autoBind: false,
            change: onChange,
            dataSource: catogory               

        }).data("kendoDropDownList");
    }

    function onChange()
             {

                   dropdownlist.select(0);
              }
```

But the dropdown is not selecting on change function. How can i do that please help me.

Comment: The dropdownlist variable must be defined out of the method, so you can refer to the same instance in your event handler. Try that first and let me know.

Comment: I don't understand what the idea is. Why do you want the first value to always be selected no matter what the user choses? Feels very odd.

Comment: @Bobby How can i declare the dropdown list variable outside the event handler when i am using the drop down list inside the grid

Comment: @Atanas korchev not only the first element i want to select the newly added element in the dropdown list

Comment: @Sri the code you have written will always select the first item when then user picks any item. I recommend checking the API documentation of the DropDownList.

Comment: @atanas the dropdownlist variable is not accessing actually that's why i am asking this question. Here i am using the dropdownlist in grid

Comment: Can you please describe what you trying to achieve. I did few grids with ddl recently, but I do not get what do you mean by newly added to the ddl. If you mean newly added to the datasource then don't use on change, but use the create.comleted on the datasource.

Comment: @Bobby_D_ In my ddl i will be having an element new if i select new then a popup  window will appear. Then i need to add another value to the ddl. Using datasource.add() method. Then i need to select newly added item in ddl. How can i do that. Hope you understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your onchange event add e as event , `e.sender.select(0)`  will do the trick.

here is the code.

```
function Change(e) {
    console.log("Event Fired"); e.sender.select(0);
    }
```